# Exercise 6 from "Measure Theory and Integration" Micheal E.Taylor, a maximal inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, harmonic-analysis, change-of-variable

I'm wrapping up Michael E. Taylor's Measure Theory book and currently tackling the exercises in Chapter 11. I'm encountering difficulties with Exercise 6, specifically at a certain point where I'm stuck. I have at my disposal the standard covering lemmas and classical maximal inequalities.

Let $\Phi: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be a monotone decreasing $C^1$ function with the property that $-s^{n} \cdot \Phi'(s) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$. Then define
$$\varphi_{r}(x) = r^{-n}\cdot \Phi(\frac{\vert x \vert}{r}),$$
and finally set $$M_{\varphi}f(x)= \sup_{r>0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \left\vert f(y) \right\vert \cdot \phi_{r}(x-y) \ dy.$$
Now prove that there exists $g \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{+})$ such that $$ \left\vert M_{\varphi}f(x) \right\vert \leq \Vert g \Vert_{L^{1}} \cdot Mf(x)$$ for every measurable $f.$

In my attempt, I proceeded as follows:
$$\begin{align*} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \vert f(y) \vert \cdot r^{-n} \cdot \Phi(\frac{\vert x -y \vert}{r}) \ dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \vert f(x-r\ s) \vert \cdot \Phi(\vert s \vert) \ ds    \\ = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \ d\rho \ \int_{S^{n-1}} \rho^{n-1} \ \Phi(\rho) \ \vert f(x-r \ \rho \ \omega) \vert \ d\omega   \\ = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \rho^{n-1} \ \Phi(\rho) \  \int_{S^{n-1}} \vert f(x-r \ \rho \ \omega) \vert \ d\omega \ d \rho \\ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \Phi(\rho)\ \frac{d}{d\rho}\left( \int_{0}^{\rho}s^{n-1} \ ds \  \int_{S^{n-1}} \vert f(x-r \ s \omega) \vert \ d\omega \right) \ d \rho \\ = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \Phi(\rho)\ \frac{1}{r^{n}} \frac{d}{d\rho} \left( \int_{0}^{r \ \rho}s^{n-1} \ ds \  \int_{S^{n-1}} \vert f(x- \ s \omega) \vert \ d\omega \right) \ d \rho \\ = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \Phi(\rho)\ \frac{1}{r^{n}} \frac{d}{d\rho} \left( \int_{B_{r\ \rho}(x)} \vert f(y) \vert \ d\omega \right) \ d \rho \\ \text{now there is an integration by parts I cannot fully justify}\\ = \int_{0}^{+\infty} -\Phi'(\rho)\ \frac{1}{r^{n}} \left( \int_{B_{r\ \rho}(x)} \vert f(y) \vert \ d\omega \right) \ d \rho.       \end{align*}$$
If I pass to the supremum on the last and first term of my chain of inequalities, I obtain
$$ \begin{align*} \left\vert M_{\varphi}f(x) \right\vert \leq \sup_{r>0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \vert f(y) \vert \cdot r^{-n} \cdot \Phi(\frac{\vert x -y \vert}{r}) \\ \leq \sup_{r>0} \int_{0}^{+\infty} -\Phi'(\rho)\ \rho^{n} \ \frac{1}{(\rho \ r)^{n}} \left( \int_{B_{r\ \rho}(x)} \vert f(y) \vert \ d\omega \right) \ d \rho \leq  \int_{0}^{+\infty} -\Phi'(\rho)\ \rho^{n} \ \sup_{r>0}  \left( \frac{1}{(\rho \ r)^{n}} \left( \int_{B_{r\ \rho}(x)} \vert f(y) \vert \ d\omega \right)   \right) \ d\rho = Mf(x) \cdot \int_{0}^{+\infty} -\Phi'(\rho)\ \rho^{n} \ d \rho.       \end{align*}$$
And we conclude by setting $g(\rho) := -\Phi'(\rho) \ \rho^{n}.$

The only passage not fully justified is the integration by parts. Why can I ignore the boundary term coming from the integration by parts? Perhaps, I can prove the inequality for a compactly supported $\Phi$ and arrive at a general $\Phi$ via approximation.

Comment: How do you obtain the first inequality? You seem to go from an integral over a sphere to an integral over a ball.

Comment: @kieransquared I think that might be the first mistake. I did not know how to use the maximal functions and wanted to obtain an integral over a ball.

Comment: @kieransquared, maybe instead of an inequality I can see the integral on the sphere as the derivative of the function $$\int_{0}^{r} ds \ \int_{S^{n-1}(0)} \left\vert f(x-s\ \rho \ \omega)  \right\vert \ d\omega  $$ and try to apply integration by parts.

Comment: @kieransquared Got it! I mistakenly used the wrong function for integrating parts. When I view 
$$ \rho^{n-1} \cdot \left\vert f(x-r \ \rho \ \omega) \right\vert$$
as the derivative of the function 
$$ \int_{0}^{\rho} t^{n-1} \cdot \int_{S^{n-1}} f(x-t \ r \ \omega ) \, d\omega$$
and apply integration by parts, everything aligns perfectly! Since I had my answer, what I should do with the question, can I answer it by myself?

Comment: @kieransquared However, I'm still dubious about why the boundary term in the integration by parts goes to zero!

Comment: @kieransquared At the moment, I have to require $\phi$ to be have limit zero at infinity, and that's ok, but I also have to suppose $f$ to be $L^{1}.$ Anyway, I am going to try it again tomorrow.

Comment: I think you might need $\Phi$ to vanish at infinity; given a $\Phi$ satisfying the assumptions, you can add 1 to it and then the derivative remains unchanged, so you wind up with the bound $|M_{\Phi+1}f| \leq \|g\|_{L^1}|Mf|$ with the $g$ you claim. But take $f = 1$, then $Mf = 1$ but $M_{\Phi+1}f \geq \int f$ (since $\Phi$ is nonnegative) so your stated bound can’t possibly hold.

Comment: @kieransquared there is definitely some hypothesis missing. I think it might be for $\Phi$ to be also compactly supported. The exercise asked to obtain the estimation using I showed you using as function $\varphi(x) = \Phi(\vert x \vert)$ instead of the function $\varphi$ of the previous exercise. In the previous exercise I had $$\varphi(x) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\chi_{B_{s}}(x)}{m(B_{s})} \ g(s) \ ds$$ where $g \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{+})$ and $g \geq 0.$ Moreover, in this previous case the norm of $g$ is the one that appears in the inequality.

Comment: I agree, there are probably some support or decay assumptions missing. For what it’s worth, I’m familiar with a similar result which says that $M_\Phi f \leq \|\Phi\|_{L^1} Mf$ for all $\Phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which are radial and radially decreasing (this can be proven by approximating $\Phi$ by linear combinations of indicators of balls). The quantity in front of $Mf$ in your bound is almost the $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ norm of $\Phi$ (as a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$) after a formal integration by parts.

Comment: @kieransquared, thank you. I was already aware of that result. Perhaps I'll make an attempt to reach out to the book's author, provided they have the time to engage in a conversation with me.